# Regex to remove repeated character pattern in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that may have a repeated character pattern, e.g.

```
'xyzzyxxyzzyxxyzzyx'
```

I need to write a regex that would replace such string with its smallest repeated pattern:

```
'xyzzyxxyzzyxxyzzyx' becomes 'xyzzyx',

'abcbaccbaabcbaccbaabcbaccba' becomes 'abcbaccba'
```

Comment: Is the pattern known, or are you looking for any repeating pattern in a string?

Comment: He's looking for the smallest repeating pattern I guess.

Answer (score 9):

Use the following:

```
> re.sub(r'(.+?)\1+', r'\1', 'xyzzyxxyzzyxxyzzyx')
'xyzzyx'
> re.sub(r'(.+?)\1+', r'\1', 'abcbaccbaabcbaccbaabcbaccba')
'abcbaccba'
> re.sub(r'(.+?)\1+', r'\1', 'iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii')
'i'
```

It basically matches a pattern that repeats itself `(.+?)\1+`, and removes everything but the repeating pattern, which is captured in the first group `\1`. Also note that using a reluctant qualifier here, i.e., `+?` will make the regex backtrack quite a lot.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/M8ZzM)**.

Comment: The problem with this is that it fails for this case:
    >>> re.sub(r'(\w+)\1+', r'\1', 'iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii') yields
    'iiiiiiiii' instead of an 'i'

Comment: @mercador: I see, make the `+` quantifier reluctant instead of greedy. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want the smallest repeating pattern, something like the following should work for you:

```
re.sub(r'^(.+?)\1+$', r'\1', input_string)
```

The `^` and `$` anchors make sure you don't get matches in the middle of the string, and by using `.+?` instead of just `.+` you will get the shortest pattern (compare results using a string like `'aaaaaaaaaa'`).

Comment: And just keep in mind that this may take quite a long time to fail if `input_string` is something like `"a" * 1000000 + "b"`.

Comment: Any ideas of regex without backtracking? The `.+?` will cause heavy backtracking.

Comment: if you read a book such as 'Programming Perl', you can find a realization of regexs with 'heavy' examples. i think, it is not a quick task for regexs.

Comment: Did some timing tests, and this regex is O(n) where n is the length of the string, so the backtracking here is not a problem.  [Catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) is a bigger issue with nested repetition where you can get exponential growth like O(2^n).  There actually might not be a more efficient method using normal string operations (not sure about this).

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex pattern and capture the first group:

```
^(.+?)\1+$
```

- `^` anchor for beginning of string/line
- `.` any character except newlines
- `+` quantifier to denote atleast 1 occurence
- `?` makes the `+` lazy instead of greedy, hence giving you the shortest pattern
- `()` capturing group
- `\1+` backreference with quantifier to denote that pattern should
  repeat atleast once
- `$` anchor for end of string/line

Test it here: [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Fa10P9Q3fB)

---

The above solution does a lot of backtracking affecting performance. If you know the which characters are not allowed in these strings, then you can use a negated characted set which eliminates backtracking. For e.g., if whitespaces are not allowed, then

```
^([^\s]+)\1+$
```