# Find repeated pattern in a string of characters using R

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a large text that contains expressions such as: `"aaaahahahahaha that was a good joke".`  after processing, I want the `"aaaaahahahaha"` to disappear, or at least, change it to simply `"ha"`.

At the moment, I am using this:

```
gsub('(.+?)\\1', '', str)
```

This works when the string with the pattern is at the beginning of the sentence, but not where is located anywhere else. So:

```
str <- "aaaahahahahaha that was a good joke"
gsub('(.+?)\\1', '', str)
#[1] "ha that was a good joke"`
```

But

```
 str <- "that was aaaahahahahaha a good joke"
 gsub('(.+?)\\1', '', str)
#[1] "that was aaaahahahahaha a good joke"
```

This question might relate to this: [find repeated pattern in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468613/regex-to-remove-repeated-character-pattern-in-a-string), but I can't find the equivalence in R.

I am assuming is very simple and perhaps I am missing something trivial, but since regular expressions are not my strength and I have already tried a bunch of things that have not worked, I was wondering if someone could help me. The question is: How to find, and substitute, repeated patterns in a string of characters in R?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\b(\S+?)\1\S*\b
```

Use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/46

For `r` use `\\b(\\S+?)\\1\\S*\\b` with `perl=TRUE` option.

Comment: This is genius.  Can you explain the logic a bit?  A simple parser still didn't elucidate to the point I could figure out the rules.

Comment: @TylerRinker `\b` is word boundary...so `\b\S*\b` will detect words assuming special characters are not there.....now `(\S+?)\1` will detect repeated strings...and then `\S*` will capture the rest...

Comment: This matches any word that starts with the first two letters being the same: aardvark, eerie, eek, eel, llama, ooh, oops, ooze, oozing. I don't think we want those to disappear.

Comment: @D_Bester mm actually requirement is not very clear