# Find repeated words in a string separated by "/"

Tags: regex, r

Assume the following vector:

```
x <- c("/default/img/irs/irs/irs/irs/irs/irs/irs/irs/irs/irs/irs/irs/IRS.html/", "something/repeat/repeat_this")
```

I want to check whether a word enclosed by `/` is repeated (Note that `/` might be missing from start and end of string). I found the following brilliant piece of regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438282/find-repeated-pattern-in-a-string-of-characters-using-r) but (after I strip special characters) I can't seem to modify it to fit my case:

```
grepl("\\b(\\S+?)\\1\\S*\\b", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE TRUE
```

I can always `str_split(x, "/")` and iterate the `duplicated()` function over the list and use an `if()` statement but that would be terribly inefficient.

Desired outcome should be a vector with TRUE or FALSE (or 1 and 0).

Comment: why not `table` instead of `duplicated` after `strsplit` and you keep only words that occur more than once (like `lapply(strsplit(x, "/"), function(y) table(y)[table(y)>1])`)

Comment: @Cath running `table` twice will be probably slower. Also, adding `fixed  = TRUE` will significantly improve performance. So with a small modification `temp <- table(unlist(strsplit(x, "/", fixed = TRUE))) ; temp[temp > 1]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I kind of heard you saying that in a part of my head before you commented actually ;-)

Comment: Well, that was easier than I thought!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following could work for you.  First, `fixed = TRUE` in `strsplit()` bypasses the regex engine and goes straight to exact matching, making the function much faster. Next, `anyDuplicated()` returns a length one integer result which will be zero if no duplicates are found, and greater than zero otherwise.  So we can split the string with `strsplit()` and iterate `anyDuplicated()` over the result. Then we can compare the resulting vector with zero.

```
vapply(strsplit(x, "/", fixed = TRUE), anyDuplicated, 1L) > 0L
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

To be safe, you may want to remove any leading `/`, since it will produce an empty character in the result from `strsplit()` and could produce misleading results in some cases (e.g. cases where the string begins with a `/` and `irs//irs` or similar occurs later in the string).  You can remove leading forward slashes with `sub("^/", "", x)`.

In summary, the ways to make your `strsplit()` idea faster are:

- use `fixed = TRUE` in `strsplit()` to bypass the regex engine
- use `anyDuplicated()` since it stops looking after it finds one match
- use `vapply()` since we know what the result type and length will be

Answer (score 8):

Other solution if you only want to check your pattern

```
grepl(x, pattern = "((.+)/).*(/\\2(/|$))", perl=T)
```

where `(.+)`represents the word itself (capture group 2) appearing before a slash, the `.*` allows an arbitrary length of characters, digits and whitespaces to occur between two equal substrings. `(/\\2(/|$))` then matches if the word occurs after a slash followed by either another slash or the end of the string (`$`).

For extraction you can use strsplit() as elaborated above.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it's giving TRUE in the second result, where it should be FALSE. OP wants exact matching.  I think this is only doing partial matching.  Furthermore, `sapply()` is not necessary.  `grepl()` is vectorized over `x`, so `grepl("(.+)/(\\1)", x, perl=TRUE)` would do it.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about grepl being vectorized! Edited the regex for exact matching

Comment: Closer, but won't work for `x <- "something/repeat/repeat_this/repeat/"`

Comment: Right, I'm going to edit the regex above so that it matches if the repetition occurs further behing