# Removing repeated characters in strings

Tags: r, regex

This question could be related with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438282/find-repeated-pattern-in-a-string-of-characters-using-r).

Unfortunately the solution given there doesn't work with my data.

I have the following vector example:

```
example<-c("ChildrenChildren", "Clothing and shoesClothing and shoes","Education, health and beautyEducation, health and beauty", "Leisure activities, travelingLeisure activities, traveling","LoansLoans","Loans and financial servicesLoans and financial services" ,"Personal transfersPersonal transfers" ,"Savings and investmentsSavings and investments","TransportationTransportation","Utility servicesUtility services")
```

And I want of course the same strings without repetition, that is:

```
  > result
 [1]   "Children" "Clothing and shoes" "Education, health and beauty"
```

Is that possible?

Comment: How did you wind up with such a vector in the first place? Seems like it would be easier to fix the step that lead to such data rather than fix it after the fact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `sub` for that, directly capturing the bit you want in the `pattern` part:

```
sub("(.+)\\1", "\\1", example)
 #[1] "Children"                      "Clothing and shoes"            "Education, health and beauty"  "Leisure activities, traveling" "Loans"                        
 #[6] "Loans and financial services"  "Personal transfers"            "Savings and investments"       "Transportation"                "Utility services"
```

`(.+)` permits to capture some pattern and `\\1` displays what you just captured so what you're trying to find is "anything twice" and then you replace with the same "anything" but just once.

Comment: I am not good with regular expressions, have you done any course or do you have any documentation?

Comment: @HenryNavarro I mainly learnt with the help page `?regex` and reading Q&A on SO ;-)

Comment: All the answer are good but I have to choose one. Each answer have been upvoted by me, and thanks to everyone

Comment: Didn't realize you can use `\\1` inside the pattern itself! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If all the strings are repeated, then they are twice as long as they need to be, so take the first half of each string:

```
> substr(example, 1, nchar(example)/2)
 [1] "Children"                      "Clothing and shoes"           
 [3] "Education, health and beauty"  "Leisure activities, traveling"
 [5] "Loans"                         "Loans and financial services" 
 [7] "Personal transfers"            "Savings and investments"      
 [9] "Transportation"                "Utility services"
```

Comment: It does strongly depend on the repeat though. @Cath's solution has the property that if a string isn't repeated then you get that whole string back instead of half of it as you do with my code.

Comment: All the answer are good but I have to choose one. Each answer have been upvoted by me, and thanks to everyone

Answer (score 3):

We could try:

```
stringr::str_remove_all(example,"[a-z].*[A-Z]")
```

Result:

```
[1] "Children"                      "Clothing and shoes"            "Education, health and beauty" 
 [4] "Leisure activities, traveling" "Loans"                         "Loans and financial services" 
 [7] "Personal transfers"            "Savings and investments"       "Transportation"               
[10] "Utility services"
```

Comment: All the answer are good but I have to choose one. Each answer have been upvoted by me, and thanks to everyone